# Converting word documents to excel with VBscript

Tags: excel, vbscript, ms-word

I'm building a tool in VBscript that would convert all of the word documents in a folder into excel documents. I need to copy everything and keep the source formatting. This works manually by ctrl-a the word document and paste to the excel document. The main problem is with ActiveDocument (i'm unsure if it's activating my word document) and i'm unsure how to do the paste to the excel document.

Here is my code so far. It makes new excel files with the same name as the word documents, but it doesn't copy the contents and paste.

```
set shApp = CreateObject("shell.application")
currentPath = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(".") 
set shFolder = shApp.NameSpace( currentPath )
set files = shFolder.Items()



for each files in files
    if files.type = "Microsoft Word 97 - 2003 Document" OR files.type = "Microsoft Word Document" then
      msgbox("Converting: "&files.path)
      Call DocConvert() 'function call to function that converts .doc to .xls

end if
next


'Opens a word document copies the contents and pastes it into an excel document of the same name
Function DocConvert()

 On Error Resume Next

 Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
        If Err <> 0 Then
            Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        End If

 objWord.Visible = True
 objWord.Documents.Open(files.path)

 ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select
 Selection.WholeStory
 Selection.Copy


 Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 objExcel.Visible = True
 Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()

 ExcelSave = replace(files.path,"doc","xls")

 objWorkbook.SaveAs(ExcelSave)

 objWord.Quit
 objExcel.Quit

End Function
```

Comment: Word files are *documents*. Excel files are *spreadsheets*. This feels so wrong.

Comment: Hmm, why do you need these in Excel? Perhaps this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? What's the purpose of putting the Word text in Excel?

Comment: `for each files in files` this is not right...  And why not pass the `file` object as a parameter to `DocConvert` ?

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` - you should cancel this with `On Error Goto 0` once you have your reference to Word, or you'll not see other errors.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't really understand what you are doing...

```
Selection.Copy
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
ExcelSave = replace(files.path,"doc","xls")
objWorkbook.SaveAs(ExcelSave)
```

You make a copy of a selection and you don't paste it anywhere? How Excel is supposed to know where to put it?
You need to Select a Cell and Paste what you have just copied. Of course you need to do this before you Quit the Excel and before you Save.